# ssl via apache php login to mariadb not working

Tags: php, apache, ssl, mariadb, debian

I have a problem which i do not fully grasp right now.
I have a webapp running on a debian server, also running apache, php and mariadb on it.
I can reach the webapp via **http://** and log in without any problems. But doing the same over **https://** throws a generic `"Can't connect: Access denied for user 'abcdef'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"` mariadb error.

ssl certificate is setup and working, opening the webapp shows the valid certificate in the browser. So i do not really understand where the problem comes.

I use **php** as **backend** and have a call from either **http** or **https** and make a connect on the **locally running mariadb, why is it working in one case but not the other?**

Any suggestions?

Comment: The connection between PHP and DB should be agnostic to whatever HTTP protocol. Are you sure your Apache config serves out the same codes for http:// and https://? Otherwise, toss in a `phpinfo()` file and access it via both protocols, and start chasing down for exotic differences.